# How does this equation gives numbers random between two values?

Tags: shell, arithmetic, random

How does this equation gives random numbers between `max` and `min` divisible by `divisibleBy`

```
echo $(((RANDOM%(max-min+divisibleBy))/divisibleBy*divisibleBy+min))
```

Comment: Isn't this more of a question for http://math.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: i dont know where to put it, it does seem like a math question [either](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1788902/how-does-this-equation-gives-numbers-random-between-two-values).I got it from advanced bash scripting guide.will just wait for a while untill i delete on of the two

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think of it as working in steps of `divsibleBy` units times an integer.

ignoring the RANDOM for the moment, `(max-min+divisbleBy)/divisibleBY` would be the width of the range in plain integers, instead of (unit x integer), so `(max-min+divisibleBy)` is the width in (unit x integers)

the `%` is a modulo operator to give you a number inside the (unit x integer) width out of `RANDOM` (which will be between 0 and 32767 itself)

the `/divisibleBy*divisibleBy` part makes sure you are not getting a non-zero remainder when inside the set of (units x integers)

the `+min`  shifts the random number (that falls within the width) back up into the target range

Comment: it was a brain twister for me